# How does the C++ runtime system know when objects go out of scope

Tags: c++, runtime, destructor

I was wondering how the C++ runtime system detects when an object goes out of scope so that
it calls the destructor accordingly to free up the occupied memory.

Thanks.

Comment: this subject is very-very interesting on C# :) Objects may be destroyed even before and object terminates it's execution.

Comment: @cprogrammer: First of all, this question doesn't have anything to do with C#. Second, no, that's not really possible in C# either. I'm not sure what cases you're referring to.

Comment: Cody: Actually it is possible. If the code in an instance method doesn't talk with other instance members, than that instance is no longer referenced. The GC would be free to run the finalizer (if any) and clean up the object at that time if it wishes to, even if that object still has code executing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is known statically at compile time

```
{
  string s; /* ctor called here */
} /* dtor called here */
```

Sometimes, it's more difficult

```
{
  again:
  {
    string s; /* ctor called here */
    goto again; /* now dtor of s is called here */
    string q; /* ctor not called. not reached. */
  } /* dtor of s and q would be called here. but not reached */
}
```

Comment: Would your second example cause a memory leak?

Comment: @Mark no. Where would it leak memory?

Comment: Never mind I missed that dtor was called on s at the goto statement.

Answer (score 27):

The runtime doesn't - the compiler keeps tabs on scope and generates the code to call the destructor. If you make a simple test application and look at the generated disassembly you'll see explicit destructor calls.

Disassembly snippet from MSVC:

```
int main() {
    std::string s1;
...
00971416  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (979290h)] 
...
    {
        std::string s2;
00971440  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (979290h)] 
...    
    }
00971452  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (979294h)] 
...
}
0097146B  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (979294h)]
```

Answer (score 6):

It has nothing to do with runtime.  The compiler keeps track of scope of every lexical variable, and adds destructor calls.

Answer (score 6):

"calling the destructor" and "freeing the memory associated with the variable" are two different things entirely.

A destructor is simply a function that C++ is nice enough to call for you when your object is going out of scope or is being explicitely deleted. The compiler generates this for you as others have said. Its a convenient way for you to clean up anything in your class that you need to clean up.

Freeing up the memory associated with something on the stack involves learning about how the stack operates. When a function is called, memory is allocated for everything on the stack by simply pushing onto the stack the amount of data needed for those variables. Though not explicitly stated in the C++ spec, the "push" really just involves letting the pointer to the top of the stack point higher (or lower) to make room for the extra variables. This is simple pointer addition. When the function returns, pointer subtraction occurs.

```
void foo()
{
    HerClass y;
    YourClass x; // stack incremented sizeof(YourClass) + sizeof(HerClass)

    return; // destructor called, 
            // then stack decremented sizeof(YourClass) + sizeof(HerClass)
}
```

Everything is popped off the stack. You can learn more about this by reading about [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

Heap memory is explicitly manually controlled by the program. Unless code is doing the explicit heap management for you, you'll need to make sure you delete everything you new.

Answer (score 5):

The scope ends with the scope. It doesn't "detect" it, the compiler writes the code in a way the destructor will be called in time.

E.g. the following code

```
if(something)
{
    MyClass test;
    test.doSomething();
}
```

Would result in machine code that does something like this:

- evaluate the jump
- jump down if required
- allocate memory for test
- call the constructor of MyClass on test
- call doSomething on test
- call the destructor of MyClass on test
- deallocate memory

Answer (score 3):

When the application enters a scoped environment (block, function call, etc.), the runtime loads the context (including local variables) for that block onto the stack.  This is an actual stack data structure.  As execution goes deeper and deeper into nested contexts, the stack gets higher and higher.  If `main()` calls `foo()` which calls `bar()`, the stack will have `main()`s context on the bottom of the stack, then `foo`'s context, then `bar`'s.  This is why infinite recursion results in "stack overflow" and throwing exceptions triggers "stack unwinding."

When execution exits that scope, that context is popped off the stack.  In C++, popping objects of the stack includes invoking the destructor for those objects.  So when `bar()` `returns`, its local variables will be popped off the stack, and the destructors for those variables will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably misunderstanding the characteristics of a few programming languages. C++ does not have a garbage collector, so it does not decide when an object has gone out of scope: the user does.

```
int main()
{
    Obj * obj = new Obj;
    Obj obj2;

    delete obj;
}
```

In the function above, you create an object *obj* in the heap, and release it when you're no longer going to use it. The object *obj2*, on the other hand, just terminates its life at the end of *main()*, as any other variable. When an object terminates its life, the destructor of the object is called automatically; the compiler inserts the calls to these destructors automatically: at the end of the function, or when operator **delete** is invoked.

Comment: "at the end of the function" should be "at the end of the control structure". In C/C++, scope does not necessarily refer to a function but to a control structure (function, `if`, `for`, etc.). Per example, an object allocated on the stack in a `for` loop will be destroyed at the end of each of the loop's iteration.

Comment: Scope is a property of lexical variables, not objects.  Dynamically allocated objects do not have scope at all.

Comment: Yep, @netcoder, and @Voigt, I just trying to answer the OP in his own terms and following the example I wrote. @twaking, you're welcome.